# CSRF protection not working with Spring Security 6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I upgraded my project to Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6, but since the upgrade the CSRF protection is no longer working.

I'm using the following configuration:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .httpBasic(withDefaults())
        .sessionManagement(session -> session
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()))
        .build();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
     UserDetails user = User.builder().username("user").password("{noop}test").authorities("user").build();
     return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
}
```

On my webpage I only have a single button:

```html
<button id="test">Test CSRF</button>
```

And the following JavaScript code:

```js
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener('click', async function() {
  console.log('Clicked');
  // This code reads the cookie from the browser
  // Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25490531
  const csrfToken = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*XSRF-TOKEN\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')?.pop();
  const result = await fetch('./api/foo', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-Token': csrfToken
    }
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

In Spring Boot 2.7.x this setup works fine, but if I upgrade my project to Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security 6, I get a 403 error with the following debug logs:

```
15:10:51.858 D         o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter: Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/api/foo
15:10:51.859 D   o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl: Responding with 403 status code
```

My guess is that this is related to the changes for [#4001](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4001). However I don't understand what I have to change to my code or if I have to XOR something.

I did check if it was due to the new deferred loading of the CSRF token, but even if I click the button a second time (and verifying that the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is set), it still doesn't work.

Comment: You must ensure that the webpage with the `test` button on it is loaded from the server each time with a fresh `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie, and is not taken from the browser cache (with an expired cookie). Check the network tab in the browser console whether this is the case.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I did that. From what I can see during debugging is that the new XOR CSRF request handler in Spring Security expects an XOR'ed CSRF token. But on the other hand, the cookie CSRF repository doesn't return an XOR'ed CSRF token but a normal one. So when I debug the CSRF handler, I see that they check the byte length of the two tokens (the expected one and the one passed as a header) and they don't match so the handler returns `null` and the call fails.

Comment: (That's also the reason why it works again if I change the CSRF handler back to the original one, as seen in the answers by both myself and Matt.)

Comment: I have the same problem in my app, the logout doesn't work for the same reason XSRF-TOKEN is absent from the cookie. I added this configuration 
`CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();         requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
http.csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(getCookieCsrfTokenRepository())
        .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)`
Now the token exists in all request cookies, but the problem is that **X-XSS-Protection** is 0 , but should be **1; mode=block**
Do you have a solution for that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I added a section to the reference documentation for migrating to 5.8 (in preparation to 6.0) that [demonstrates a solution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework) for this issue, which has since been updated in later versions of the documentation.

**TL;DR** See [CSRF with JavaScript Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript)

The issue here is that Angular (and your example code above) are using the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie directly. Prior to Spring Security 6, this was fine. But unfortunately, the cookie is actually used to persist the raw token, and with Spring Security 6, the raw token is not accepted by default. Ideally, front-end frameworks would be able to use another source to get the token, such as an `X-XSRF-TOKEN` response header.

However, even with Spring Security 6, such a response header is not provided out of the box, though it could be a possible enhancement worth suggesting. I have not yet suggested such an enhancement since Javascript frameworks would not be able to use it by default.

For now, you will need to work around the problem by configuring Spring Security 6 to accept raw tokens, as suggested in the section I linked above. The suggestion allows raw tokens to be submitted, but continues to use the `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` to make available the hashed version of the request attribute (e.g. `request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName())` or `request.getAttribute("_csrf")`), in case anything renders the CSRF token to an HTML response which could be vulnerable to BREACH.

I would recommend finding a reputable source for researching BREACH more thoroughly, but unfortunately I cannot claim to be such a source.

**Update:** [This article](https://blog.qualys.com/product-tech/2013/08/07/defending-against-the-breach-attack) is one possible starting point.

I would also recommend keeping an eye on Spring Security issues for now, as things may change quickly once the community begins consuming Spring Security 6. You can use [this filter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+csrf) as a possible way to keep track of CSRF-related issues.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I fail to understand the implications. Given that the CSRF Token is never rendered to a HTML page it seems like I don't really need the new implementation anyway, right?
Personally I don't get the feature as a whole. How can this "per request" CSRF Token even be generated in a world of multiple parallel calls? It's not like you can create a new one once the old one is handed in, since already running parallel requests can not now about it.

Comment: @MarioB, the underlying csrf token does not change per request, but is encoded with random bytes so it can provide out-of-the-box protection for BREACH. If you don't require this protection, you can certainly revert to normal CSRF protection using `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler`.

Comment: Was there a change about the creation of csrf token too? After upgrading, I now see the first protected request failing, only during the failed request the csrf token is created and subsequent requests succeed.

Comment: Sorry @Felix, I think I'd need more details to fully answer your question. Mind opening a new SO question?

Comment: @Felix My guess is that it's due to the deferred loading of the CSRF token. Check the chapter before the BREACH attack chapter in the documentation linked by Steve.

Comment: @g00glen00b thanks, that’s a good point. I will check that during the weekend. If it doesn’t work i will open a new question

Comment: I can confirm my setup works with the example to go back to 5.8 behavior as linked in the documentation linked by Steve. This is likely required because I use a special setup for authentication, which uses no sessions (`SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`). Every request is authenticated through a custom `SecurityContextRepository` and no sessions are created.

Comment: I added this CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to my security configuration, but I still have issues with CSRF. I would appriciate if you take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75080739/spring-security-6-post-requests-are-unauthorised-with-permitall/75083797?noredirect=1#comment132518265_75083797

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg  I read the reference documentation like 10 times, but I am still not sure. It seems to say (in the NOTE box) that BREACH protection is only necessary if I include the token in the response body. Reversely, this seems to say that if I DO NOT return the token in the body (it's transferred as a cookie) that protection is meaningless and safe to be deactivated. Correct?

Comment: @MarioB I apologize that it was not clear to you. Please don't hesitate to open an issue with any suggested improvements. Regarding your question, that is not exactly what I was trying to convey with the NOTE under "I am using AngularJS or another Javascript framework." Above the NOTE it says "This is the RECOMMENDED way...". The NOTE intends to let you know that the protection is there for anything that includes the token in the response body (such as html responses). This is because you may be returning HTML somewhere and not know it. Disable BREACH only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: This helped me. I suggest putting the core content from that first link in here, to make the answer self-contained and more stable.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg Appreciate your answers but is there any further details on the question of MarioB? I am stumbling upon the exact same question why it might be safe to have the raw CSRF token in a cookie but not in the response body. Both are part of the same HTTP(S) response and should be equally exposed to BREACH. Any further info, links would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @RaHe I've added a link to an article you can start with. I won't attempt to be an authoritative source on BREACH so you will need to do some reading.

Answer (score 21):

We have an angular angular application with spring-boot. We tried to migrate to spring-boot 3 (Spring Security 6). And we faced the same problem.

We tried many methods including some of the solutions from this question's answer but we failed. After spending time we found the solution from the spring security [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#servlet-opt-in-defer-loading-csrf-token).

What we need to do is, set the `CsrfRequestAttributeName` to `null` in the configuration.

```
requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
```

**What actually happened:**
The CsrfToken will be loaded on each request in Spring Security version 5 by default. This means that in a typical setup, every request—even those that are not necessary—must have the HttpSession read.

The default behavior of Spring Security 6 is to postpone looking up the CsrfToken until it is required.

Our application needs the token every time. So, We need to opt into the 5.8 defaults.

The example code is given below (from [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#servlet-opt-in-defer-loading-csrf-token)):

```
@Bean
DefaultSecurityFilterChain springSecurity(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
    // set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
    requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
    http
        // ...
        .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
        );
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand this solution, it is not using `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` and, as so, is exposed to BREACH. What about using `new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()` and then `csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler::handle)` as instructed in the doc linked in the accepted answer?

Comment: @ch4mp and others my use case and configuration is exactly as described in this answer. `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` works, but when i just replace it with `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` in the above snippet, csrf doesn't work.  what am i missing?

Comment: Maybe you didn't configured the required filter. Also, In my answer below, I'm not passing the all `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler`. I just give a reference to its `handle` method. You could give a try to [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) which auto configures the handler and the filter. If you don't want to use it, you can still read the source: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/139339c672fb57611bae5a20b0be27f698b253f3/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oidc/starter/synchronised/ServletConfigurationSupport.java#L121

Comment: @keemahs `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` probably won't work out of the box as it expects encrypted tokens.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation pointed by @steve-reisenberg is adapted to servlets (and is now outdated, the [new version is there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa-configuration))

Here is the adaptation for webflux apps (like `spring-cloud-gateway`):

```java
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler()));
```

with:

```java
/**
 * Adapted from https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa
 */
static final class SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler extends ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {
    private final ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate = new XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

    @Override
    public void handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken) {
        /*
         * Always use XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to provide BREACH protection of the CsrfToken when it is rendered in the response body.
         */
        this.delegate.handle(exchange, csrfToken);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<String> resolveCsrfTokenValue(ServerWebExchange exchange, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        final var hasHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(csrfToken.getHeaderName()).stream().filter(StringUtils::hasText).count() > 0;
        return hasHeader ? super.resolveCsrfTokenValue(exchange, csrfToken) : this.delegate.resolveCsrfTokenValue(exchange, csrfToken);
    }
}

@Bean
WebFilter csrfCookieWebFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(CsrfToken.class.getName(), Mono.empty()).subscribe();
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```

**This should protect against both CSRF and BREACH** (as opposed to the answers referencing (Server)CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler which are exposed to BREACH).

Comment: Thanx, that's the answer that really worked for my Angular+Java application.

Answer (score 5):

As of Spring Security 6.0.1 and Spring Boot 3.0.2, following [the instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_angularjs_or_another_javascript_framework) from the accepted answer fails on the first request but succeeds thereafter. The reason it fails on the first request is because the token's cookie never gets created until a protected method is invoked. This is because the method `CookieCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken` only gets called when the `CsrfFilter` calls `deferredCsrfToken.get()`, which only gets called on POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE methods. Unfortunately, under the current implementation, that means the client has to expect a failure on the first request. Under previous versions of Spring Security, we used to be able to count on the token's cookie being included in the response to GET, HEAD, or OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Any ideas on how to deal with this first failure? Are we expected to do some form of innocuous POST to get past this?

Comment: You are probably missing `addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)`. I got this from [the doc I link in my answer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa-configuration).

Answer (score 2):

I currently worked around the problem by disabling the `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` like this:

```java
.csrf(csrf -> csrf
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    // Added this:
    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()))
```

However, this means that I'm likely vulnerable against the BREACH attack.

Comment: Yes, you are. The accepted answer (posted after yours) references a solution protecting against both CSRF and BREACH for servlets (like your app is, obviously) and I just posted the equivalent for reactive apps.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this! I was able to use it to solve a similar project in a JHipster + Spring Boot 3 app. However, it seems the class name might've changed recently. Here's what I had to use:

```java
.csrf(csrf -> csrf
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I only took a quick look but that appears to be the reactive counterpart to the `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` class. I'm just not very experienced in security-stuff but I guess it's less secure than `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler ` (or the reactive `XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` counterpart) so I wonder if there's a solution that utilizes the XOR-logic.

Comment: This is actually disabling the `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` and exposing to BREACH attacks.

Comment: currently XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler cannot do test.
`with(csrf())` doesn't support `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler`

Comment: @jinseok.oh this only applies to the servlet implementation: `SecurityMockServerConfigurers.csrf()` works with `XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` in reactive applications (like `spring-cloud-gateway`). I opened [an issue for `with(csrf())` used with `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler `](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14125). As you had found this problem, maybe could you have considered opening such an issue yourself?

Comment: @ch4mp
 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12774
spring security dosn't support XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler to test

Comment: @jinseok.oh thank you for this link (and sorry I did not find it). I need to better grasp all it contains, but at first glance, I'm surprised it works out of the box in reactive stack and not in servlet one. I believe that at minimum, the servlet test framework should contain the additional post processor Spring Security team members talk about (but maybe can we find a way for the existing one to auto adapt to Xor)

Comment: @jinseok.oh as commented by spring-security team member in [the ticket I oppened](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14125), the bug doesn't apply with [latest configuration recommendations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa-configuration). I updated [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/) to apply this new conf snippet when we choose `com.c4-soft.springaddons.oidc.client.csrf=cookie-accessible-from-js` (version `7.1.14`)

Answer (score 1):

Using the accepted answer breaks tests that require CSRF using Spring Security's `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.crsf()` I can either only use  `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler`, or `XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` in Spring Boot's CSRF configuration, both give positive test results.

Using the accepted answer makes Angular work but breaks tests.

So the only workaround at the moment seems to be using `CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler` and so effectively disabling Spring Security's BREACH-protection.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an issue for a different scenario where you need to send the CSRF token with a header through JavaScript which wasn't clear in the documentation. If you have a multi-page app like one where you mostly mount React components inside the HTML, it might be useful for you.

Basically what you need is to use X-CSRF-TOKEN header using the default CSRF configuration.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/13009

Answer (score 0):

Here is an solution for postman test script if you want to use spring security 6 default csrf handler (XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler):

```
const createXoredCsrfToken = (token) => {
  const tokenBytes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
    tokenBytes.push(token.charCodeAt(i));
  }

  const randomBytes = new Uint8Array(tokenBytes.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < randomBytes.length; i++) {
    randomBytes[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  }

  const xoredBytes = xorCsrf(randomBytes, tokenBytes);
  const combinedBytes = new Uint8Array(tokenBytes.length + randomBytes.length);
  combinedBytes.set(randomBytes);
  combinedBytes.set(xoredBytes, randomBytes.length);

  return btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, combinedBytes))
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=+$/, '');
};

const xorCsrf = (randomBytes, csrfBytes) => {
  if (csrfBytes.length < randomBytes.length) {
    return null;
  }
  const len = Math.min(randomBytes.length, csrfBytes.length);
  const xoredCsrf = new Uint8Array(len);
  xoredCsrf.set(csrfBytes.slice(0, len));
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    xoredCsrf[i] ^= randomBytes[i];
  }
  return xoredCsrf;
};

//Replace XSFR-TOKEN with your cookie name
var xsrfCookie = postman.getResponseCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xsrf-token", createXoredCsrfToken(xsrfCookie.value));
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I have an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')` on last line (`xsrfCookie.value`), how can I fix that?
I think XSRF-TOKEN is default cookie name generated with spring security, so it should be correct, right?

Answer (score -1):

This is what it works for me

```html
CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
// set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
delegate.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);
// Use only the handle() method of XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler and the
// default implementation of resolveCsrfTokenValue() from CsrfTokenRequestHandler
CsrfTokenRequestHandler requestHandler = delegate::handle;

...

.csrf((csrf) -> csrf
   .csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository)
   .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
)
```