# Receiving 403 Forbidden error for controller methods with HTTP methods PUT or POST. This is happening after migrating from Springboot 2.7.17 to 3.1.5

Tags: spring, security, http-status-code-403

I have upgraded Springboot from 2.7.17 to 3.1.5. I have updated the security config classes by following the guide [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html). Some issues arose which I was able to fix. However, Now, I'm stuck with 403 forbidden issue for apis with http methods PUT or POST.

Apis which are failing:

POST /app/order/comment

PUT /app/order

Apis which are successful :

All apis with GET.

My Security Config

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppConfigProperties.class)
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebappSecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String CUSTOM_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "CUSTOM-XSRF-TOKEN";

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain internalAPISecurityConfig(HttpSecurity http, AppConfigProperties configProps) throws Exception {

        String camundaWebAppUrlPattern = "/camunda/**";

        CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();

       
        csrfRepository.setCookieName(CUSTOM_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);

        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                    .ignoringRequestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(camundaWebAppUrlPattern))
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfRepository)
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                authorize.requestMatchers( AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(HttpMethod.GET, "/favicon.ico")).permitAll()
               
                        .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher(camundaWebAppUrlPattern)).hasRole("ADMIN")
                
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/app/**")).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher( "/engine-rest/**")).hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                
                .requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/error")).authenticated()
                
                .anyRequest().denyAll();
            }
            )
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
                // Redirect URL from config
                .logoutSuccessUrl(configProps.getLogoutUrl())
            )
        ;
       
        http.apply(new RequestHeaderAuthenticationConfigurer());

        return http.build();
    }
```

My Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductOrderService productOrderService;

    @Autowired
    private AuditService auditService;

    
    @PutMapping("/activities")
    @PreAuthorize("!hasRole('ROLE_VISITOR')")
    public CustomResponse activityUpdate(@RequestBody ActivitiesUpdateDto activitiesUpdateDto)
            throws JsonProcessingException {
        return productOrderService.activityUpdate(activitiesUpdateDto);
    }

    
    @GetMapping("/orders/products")
    public List<OrderDto> getOrders(@RequestParam("search") Optional<String> searchTerm) {
        return productOrderService.fetchOrders(searchTerm.isPresent() ? searchTerm.get() : null);
    }
    
    
    @PutMapping("/order")
    @PreAuthorize("!hasRole('ROLE_VISITOR')")
    public CustomResponse updateOrder(@RequestBody OrderUpdateDto orderUpdateDto) {

        return productOrderService.updateOrder(orderUpdateDto);

    }

    @PostMapping("/order/comment")
    public CustomerResponse addComment(@RequestBody CommentDto commenteDto) {

        return productOrderService.addComment(commenteDto);

    }

}
```

For all api calls, a request header with header name "Cookie" is being sent.
 `Cookie: Idea-56ec4e87=6d30aeb7-9c46-4d74-be5b-18c896652a0c; CUSTOM-XSRF-TOKEN=527851d7-ac94-424a-b55f-bf7b6a1c1d6c; JSESSIONID=9A9C968680E61F50CD936B6C7199F631`

Security config before the springboot upgrade:

```
SecurityFilterChain internalAPISecurityConfig(HttpSecurity http, AppConfigProperties configProps)
        throws Exception {

    String camundaWebAppUrlPattern = "/camunda/**";

    String[] staticRessourceUrlPatterns = new String[] { "/favicon.ico" };

    CookieCsrfTokenRepository csrfRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
    csrfRepository.setCookieName(CUSTOM_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);

   
    http
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf
                .ignoringAntMatchers(camundaWebAppUrlPattern)
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfRepository)
        )
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
           .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, staticRessourceUrlPatterns).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(camundaWebAppUrlPattern).hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/app/**", "/engine-rest/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/error").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
        )
        .logout(logout -> logout
            .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl(ConfigProps.getLogoutUrl())
        );
    http.apply(new RequestHeaderAuthenticationConfigurer());

    return http.build();
}
```

I would be thankful for any help to resolve this issue.

**What have I tried so far**

1. I have disabled the csrf using csrf.disable(). Then all apis are accessible. However, it does not meet client's requirement. So, I need to keep the csrf enabled.
2. Removed this annotation @PreAuthorize("!hasRole('ROLE_VISITOR')") for a POST method addComment(@RequestBody CommentDto commenteDto). Still this was failing with 403
3. Changed the annotation  @PreAuthorize("!hasRole('ROLE_VISITOR')")  to  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')"). Still the same issue. Even tried by removing ROLE_ prefix. Same result.

Comment: could you share `internalAPISecurityConfig` before migration ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa - Added the security config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html).

> In Spring Security 5, the default behavior is that the CsrfToken will
> be loaded on every request. This means that in a typical setup, the
> HttpSession must be read for every request even if it is unnecessary.
>
> In Spring Security 6, the default is that the lookup of the CsrfToken
> will be deferred until it is needed.

As a fix you have to change a little bit `internalAPISecurityConfig`, exactly next one change:

```
CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
// set the name of the attribute the CsrfToken will be populated on
requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
```

And then in `configuration` part also set `csrfTokenRequestHandler`

```
http
    .csrf(csrf -> csrf
            .ignoringAntMatchers(camundaWebAppUrlPattern)
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfRepository)

            .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)

    )
```

Also more discussion about this topic you can find [csrf-protection-not-working-with-spring-security-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447118/csrf-protection-not-working-with-spring-security-6)

Comment: Thanks.! It is working with a small update.

requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName(null);