# CSRF protection with spring cloud gateway getting "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" error

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud, csrf, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to implement CSRF protection with spring cloud gateway, XSRF-TOKEN cookie is setting to browser but when I add the cookie value as header `"X-XSRF-TOKEN: somevalue"`
I'm getting error as **An expected CSRF token cannot be found**

here is my security config code

```
import org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfToken;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
      ServerHttpSecurity http, ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

    http.csrf(
            csrfSpec ->
                csrfSpec
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler()))
        .authorizeExchange(
            authorizeExchangeSpec ->
                authorizeExchangeSpec
                    .anyExchange()
                    .authenticated())
       
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .logout();
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  WebFilter csrfCookieWebFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
      exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(CsrfToken.class.getName(), Mono.empty()).subscribe();
      return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
  }
```

SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler:

```
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class SpaServerCsrfTokenRequestHandler extends ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {

  private final ServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler delegate =
      new XorServerCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

  @Override
  public void handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken) {
    this.delegate.handle(exchange, csrfToken);
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<String> resolveCsrfTokenValue(ServerWebExchange exchange, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
    if (exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getOrEmpty(csrfToken.getHeaderName()).stream()
        .anyMatch(StringUtils::hasText)) {
      return super.resolveCsrfTokenValue(exchange, csrfToken);
    }
    return this.delegate.resolveCsrfTokenValue(exchange, csrfToken);
  }
}
```

I have took the references from
[CSRF protection not working with Spring Security 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447118/csrf-protection-not-working-with-spring-security-6)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa

can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Using the code you have provided here I'm unable to reproduce your issue. Can you provide an example of the request you're trying to make? Have you tried making a request from Postman or curl to eliminate any issues with the spa?

Comment: Hi @SteveRiesenberg I have added minimal, reproducible example in the git here is the link: https://github.com/VishalKumar-B/stack-overflow/tree/main/gateway-csrf

Comment: Thanks. Based on the steps documented in your readme, it looks as though you are missing the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. Since you have chosen to store the token in a cookie, it is required as part of the request. Can you try again with the cookie included?

Comment: Thanks @SteveRiesenberg It's working, Since we are storing the token in cookie we need to include the cookie along with the header.